Dart/Flutter - wrap on next line with 1 or several widgets
I have 4 fixed size widgets, i want to wrap them if parent width is getting lower
When i tried it, size of fixed widgets starts to change or big space between them, normal Wrap widget for 1 widget works fine, Wrap and 2 Rows with 2 widgets in them works fine too, but not when i need both of this methods, that's the problem
i tried GridView, Layoutbuilder and other solutions.
I expects wrapping widgets like this: in the beginning there is 4 widgets in a row (not in widget named Row), when less space is - 2 in a row and 2 in a column, in the end it's 4 rows and 1 column.
So it need to Wrap third and forth widget for the first time, and in second wrap all widgets in 1 column

I think you can use a combination of Wrap and Row widgets.use a Column to group the widgets.
in the first row,use a Row to display the first two widgets.
in the second row,use a Wrap widget to wrap the third and fourth widgets.
calculate the itemWidth based on the maximum width of the container, divided by the number of widgets per row.kind of like this:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    final maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
    final itemWidth = (maxWidth - 16) / 2; // 16 for the margin
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: itemWidth,
              height: 100,
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Widget 0'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: itemWidth,
              height: 100,
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Widget 1'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Wrap(
          spacing: 8,
          runSpacing: 8,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: itemWidth,
              height: 100,
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Widget 2'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: itemWidth,
              height: 100,
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Widget 3'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);

}

LayoutBuilder will give me his width, but how can i wrap third and forth widgets at the first time and all on second? Even if LayoutBuilder will not make giant spaces between widgets

I hope this edited solution helps you.
